# I'm trying to do Ackermann's Function on IBasic

Tags: function

> Ackermann's Function is a recursive mathematical algorithm that can be used to test how well a computer performs recursion. Design a function `ackermann(m,n)`, which solves Ackermann's Function.  Use the following logic in your function:
>
> ```
> If m = 0, then return n + 1  
> If n = 0 then return ackermann(m-1, 1)  
> Otherwise, return ackermann(m-1, ackermann(m, n-1))
> ```

The program stops after it hits 13.  Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

```
declare main()
declare ackermann(m:int, n:int)

openconsole
main()
print:print "Press any key to quit...",
do:until inkey$<>""
closeconsole
end

sub main()
 def counter, m, n:int
 counter = 0
 for counter = 1 to 100
  print ackermann(counter)
 next counter
return

sub ackermann(m, n)
 if m = 0
  return = n + 1
 else
  if n = 0
   return = ackermann(m - 1, 1)
  else
    return = ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1))
  endif
endif
return
```

Comment: Is this a stack size/memory limit? I know some languages will halt large recursive calls for fear of infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is

```
print ackermann(counter)
```

but your function is

```
sub ackermann(m, n)
```

You need to send a second parameter in the first call.

Comment: I saw that too; but I'm really curious as to how it got to 13 but couldn't continue if that's the cause of the error.

Comment: yeh, I've been trying find IBasic syntax on the web so I could see what's up with that, but all I can find is cheap download sites, no real info anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do note that Ackermann's function grows incredibly quickly - values above m,n > (3,4) are going to have a LOT of digits and if you go more than even about (4,4) you'll quickly find numbers that could quite possibly fill up your memory entirely with digits...

Refer [to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Table_of_values) to see the magnitude of the numbers you are trying to compute...

Answer (score 0):

```
declare main()
declare ackermann(m:int, n:int)


openconsole
main()
print:print "Press any key to quit...",
do:until inkey$<>""
closeconsole
end

sub main()
print  Ackermann(3,5)
return

sub ackermann(m, n)
    if m = 0
        return = n + 1
    else
        if n = 0
            return = ackermann(m - 1, 1)
        else
             return = ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1))
        endif
    endif
return
```